# Align feature map with ego motion (problem of zooming ratio )

Tags: image, pytorch, lstm, pixel, affinetransform

I want to align the feature map using ego motion, as mentioned in the paper [An LSTM Approach to Temporal 3D Object Detection in LiDAR Point Clouds](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.12392)

I use [VoxelNet](https://github.com/open-mmlab/OpenPCDet) as backbone, which will shrink the image for 8 times. The size of my voxel is `0.1m x 0.1m x 0.2m(height)`

So given an input bird-eye-view image size of `1408 x 1024`,

the extracted feature map size would be `176 x 128`, shrunk for 8 times.

---

The ego translation of the car between the "images"(point clouds actually) is 1 meter in both x and y direction. Am I right to adjust the feature map for 1.25 pixels?

```
1m/0.1m = 10  # meter to pixel
10/8 = 1.25   # shrink ratio of the network
```

However, though experiments, I found the feature maps align better if I adjust the feature map with only 1/32 pixel for the 1 meter translation in real world.

---

Ps. I am using the function `torch.nn.functional.affine_grid` to perform the translation, which takes a 2x3 affine matrix as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the function `torch.nn.functional.affine_grid` I used.

I didn't fully understand this function before I use it.

[These vivid images](https://www.cnblogs.com/king-lps/p/12076159.html) would be very helpful on showing what this function actually do(with comparison to the affine transformations in Numpy.